# trouble formatting firebase Firestore data when getting for my flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to firebase and I'm trying to implement instagram like stories to my flutter app using the "story" plugin.

I am trying to call this data:

[image]

the trouble I am having is trying to find a way to get and format the data in the "file" array.

this is my current code:

pubspec.yaml:

```
dependencies:
  story: ^0.4.0
```

story models:

```
class StoryModel {
  final String displayName;
  final String avatarUrl;
  final String ownerId;
  final List file;

  StoryModel({this.displayName, this.avatarUrl, this.ownerId, this.file});

  factory StoryModel.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc){
    return StoryModel(
      displayName: doc.data()['displayName'] ?? '',
      ownerId: doc.data()['ownerId'] ?? '',
      avatarUrl: doc.data()['avatarUrl'] ?? '',
      file: doc.data()['file'] as List,
    );
  }
}

class StoryFile {
  final String filetype;
  final String mediaUrl;
  final String postId;

  StoryFile({this.mediaUrl, this.postId, this.filetype});

  factory StoryFile.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc){
    return StoryFile(
      filetype: doc.data()['filetype'],
      mediaUrl: doc.data()['mediaUrl'],
      postId: doc.data()['postId']
    );
  }
}
```

trouble section:

```
                      FutureBuilder(
                        future: storyRef.where('canView', arrayContains: currentUserModel.uid).get(),
                        builder: (context, snap) {
                          if(!snap.hasData) {
                            return Center(child: Text('error'),);
                          } else {
                            QuerySnapshot snapshot = snap.data;
                            List<StoryModel> storyPosts = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => StoryModel.fromDocument(doc)).toList();
                          return Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                          height: 150,
                          child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: 6,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 28),
                            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                            physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                              return Row(
                                children: [
                                  Column(children: [
                                    GestureDetector(
                                      child: Container(
                                        height: 100,
                                        width: 100,
                                        margin:
                                        EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                            border: Border.all(
                                                color: Colors.blue,
                                                width: 3),
                                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                            color: Colors.grey
                                            )
                                      ),
                                      onTap: () {
                                        print('Navigate to story View');
                                      },
                                    ),
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                          top: 5, right: 22),
                                      child: Text(
                                        'insert name',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                                            color: Colors.blue[800],
                                            fontSize: 20,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w700
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ]),
                                ],
                              );
                            },
                          ),
                        );}
                        }
                      )
```

This code works fine getting the "StoryModel" data but I still need a way to get the "StoryFile" data from each individual "file" from Firestore and I can't figure out a code that works in the way I want it to.

so I need a way to get a List of "StoryFile" from each individual document preferably in the .fromdocument method as part of the "StoryModel" class if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slight change in your model can do the work for you. Now you can get a list of `StoryFile` and can access properties of it.

```
class StoryModel {
  final String displayName;
  final String avatarUrl;
  final String ownerId;
  final List<StoryFile> file;

  StoryModel({this.displayName, this.avatarUrl, this.ownerId, this.file});

  factory StoryModel.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc){
///make list of files before returning [StoryModel] instance
 List<StoryFile> list = (doc.data()['file'] as List).map((e)=>StoryFile.fromMap(e)).toList();

    return StoryModel(
      displayName: doc.data()['displayName'] ?? '',
      ownerId: doc.data()['ownerId'] ?? '',
      avatarUrl: doc.data()['avatarUrl'] ?? '',
      file: list,
    );
  }
}

class StoryFile {
  final String filetype;
  final String mediaUrl;
  final String postId;

  StoryFile({this.mediaUrl, this.postId, this.filetype});

  factory StoryFile.fromMap(Map doc){
    return StoryFile(
      filetype: doc['filetype'],
      mediaUrl: doc['mediaUrl'],
      postId: doc['postId']
    );
  }
}
```